# Abspath for templates folder in Flask is surprising?

Tags: python, flask

I am building a Flask project. My "templates" folder is a subdirectory of "app" folder. The code starts in styleprive.py which is in app with the line "From app import app". This triggers **init**.py inside app.

When I run:

`os.path.abspath(app.template_folder)`

The result is surprising I think: /Users/egarcialopez/local_programming/styleprive/templates
and not /Users/egarcialopez/local_programming/styleprive/app/templates

Why does app not show up?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `os.path.abspath("app/template_folder")`

Comment: thanks. I guess my question is: if app.template_folder keeps the location of "templates" why my code does not return the right location. Trying to understand then what app.template_folder really means?